# Cannot figure out ClassNotFoundException error

Tags: java, constructor, arraylist, runtime-error, classnotfoundexception

Here is my code:

**Getters, Setters, and imports are excluded**

Part Class:

```
public class Part{
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private int quantity;
    private BigDecimal purchaseprice;
    private BigDecimal saleprice;
    private ArrayList<String> subparts;
    private String description;

    public Part(String File, String ID)
    {
        Part TempP = DataAccess.getPart(File, ID);
        this.name = TempP.name;
        this.id = TempP.id;
        this.quantity = TempP.quantity;
        this.purchaseprice = TempP.purchaseprice;
        this.saleprice = TempP.saleprice;
        this.subparts = TempP.subparts;
        this.description = TempP.description;
    }

    public Part(){}

    public Part(String name, String id, int quantity, BigDecimal purchaseprice,
            BigDecimal saleprice, ArrayList<String> subparts, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.purchaseprice = purchaseprice;
        this.saleprice = saleprice;
        this.subparts = subparts;
        this.description = description;
    }
```

Data Access Class:

```
public class DataAccess
{    
    public static ArrayList<Part> getAllParts(String aFile){
        ArrayList<Part> PartList = new ArrayList<Part>();
        try{
            BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
            while(true){
                String TempS[];
                TempS = fin.readLine().split(",");
                if(TempS[0] == null){break;}
                ArrayList<String> subparts = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int i = 6; i < TempS.length; i++){
                    subparts.add(TempS[i]);
                }
                PartList.add(new Part(TempS[1], TempS[0],Integer.valueOf(TempS[2]),BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(TempS[3])),BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(TempS[4])),subparts,TempS[5]));
            }
            fin.close();
            return PartList;
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            return PartList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return PartList;
    }
```

So the problem is that it executes perfectly as planned until it hits `PartList.add(new Part(TempS[1], TempS[0],Integer.valueOf(TempS[2]),BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(TempS[3])),BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(TempS[4])),subparts,TempS[5]));` and then it throws a `ClassNotFoundException`, I have traced it completely through the eclipse debugger and all of the data is correct... Can someone tell me what I've done wrong? and any other suggestions for my code would be appreciated as well...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DataAccess.getAllParts(DataAccess.java:42)
    at MainController.SummonParts(MainController.java:38)
    at MainController.main(MainController.java:11)
```

The debugger reads a ClassNotFound Error on line 48 before it crashes...

Comment: Please enter the stack trace

Comment: ClassNotFoundException exception is related to classpath, class loading etc. Not related to data. You may be missing some libraries?

Comment: Which class is missing? And is it not found during compile or run time?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException         
 at DataAccess.getAllParts(DataAccess.java:48)
 at MainController.SummonParts(MainController.java:38)
 at MainController.main(MainController.java:11)`

Comment: According to the debugger it's the `Part` class that's missing...

Comment: @Sniz - You are wrong. Read at the error you just posted. It does not say **anything** about a missing class.

Comment: The `6` in ` for(int i = 6; i < TempS.length; i++)` is probably an error.

Comment: If you're indeed getting `ClassNotFoundException` then please provide its stack trace.  What do you mean by "*debugger reads*"? Where is that?

Comment: @Eric Jablow The file input is written like this: "123456789,PartA,1000,15,20,A part,subpart1,subpart2"

Comment: You completely lost me here. What does your file content has to do with anything here?

Comment: I don't know how I can paste the debugger feed, but I was walking through step by step and it runs fine until `PartList.add(...` then it crashes and the error says "ClassNotFoundException(Throwable).<init>(String, Throwable) line: 286"

Comment: Is this the **entire** error? Are there more lines after that? What if you run it without debugger?  Can you capture the complete error then?

Comment: Error without debugger: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at DataAccess.getAllParts(DataAccess.java:41) at MainController.SummonParts(MainController.java:38) at MainController.main(MainController.java:11)` which line 41 is `TempS = fin.readLine().split(","); `

Comment: Usually when a ClassNotFoundException occurs, the stack trace lists the class its looking for.  Since the error is occuring on that line, are you sure you're importing `BufferedReader` and `FileReader`?  In addition, in the debugger, what is `fin` initialized as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `6` is a magic number; replace it by a symbolic constant.  In fact, do the same for `0`, `1`, etc.
- You still aren't following the Java Naming Conventions:

  - Variables are camelCased.
  - Classes are capitalized and CamelCased.
  - Enums are ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES.
- Your names should be more specific. `TempS` and `DataAccess` say nothing about the type of object they deal with.

  - Perhaps `PartDAO` instead of `DataAccess`.
  - Perhaps `partData` instead of `TempS`.
- And, please don't use statics for so much.  Have your `main` method initialize an object and tell it to do the work. This way, you can split your method into smaller ones that you can test.
- Close your streams in `finally` blocks or use Java 7 try-with-resources.
- The `FileNotFoundException` should not be ignored, just returning an empty list.
- Prefer a logging system over `e.printStackTrace()`.  Look at `logback`.
- Don't declare your variables as `ArrayList`s; program to the interface instead and make them `List`s.
- Format your code so you don't go past column 80 or so.
- `BufferedReader.readLine()` returns `null` at end-of-file.  So, the program reaches the end of file, it calls `null.split(",")`.
- Is there any chance you will deal with csv files include escapes because an item has a comma or quote in it?  Look at csv libraries.
- `BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(TempS[3]))` is much too complex.  In fact, `BigDecimal` has a constructor that takes a `String`, and that's the preferred one to use.  So, `new BigDecimal(TempS[3])` is better.  On the other hand, is there any chance that the file might have `$19.38` in it instead of `19.38`?  You might want to look at `MessageFormat` instead.

Comment: Sorry for the naming conventions we never covered that in class. I fixed it with the `null.split(",")` Thank you...

Comment: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html for oracle's official word.  This was written before enums.  If you don't follow them, experienced readers will get confused.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Part> PartList = null;
```

and then

```
PartList.add(...);
```

leads to **NPE** - `NullPointerException`

**EDIT**

I suggest you change your `while` loop to something like this:

```
    String line;           
    while((line=fin.readLine()) != null){
        String[] TempS = line.split(",");
        ArrayList<String> subparts = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 6; i < TempS.length; i++){
            subparts.add(TempS[i]);
        }
        PartList.add(new Part(TempS[1], TempS[0],Integer.valueOf(TempS[2]),BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(TempS[3])),BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(TempS[4])),subparts,TempS[5]));
    }
```

Please note that I'm just showing the logic.  It's still possible that you have other errors there.

Comment: I use `ArrayList<String> subparts = new ArrayList<String>();` not `= null`

Comment: PM is right you are not creating PartList not subparts. You also have to create ArrayList<Part> PartList = new ArrayList<Part>();

Comment: Problem is not with `subparts` but with `PartList`. You are invoking `add()` method on a `null` object.

Comment: OK. Then post your updated code and the exact error you're getting.

Comment: Does not make any sense. Sorry.  After you properly initialized `PartList` what exact error (if any) are you getting **now**?  How exactly "*it is still not working*"?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at DataAccess.getAllParts(DataAccess.java:41)
 at MainController.SummonParts(MainController.java:38)
 at MainController.main(MainController.java:11)` which line 41 is `TempS = fin.readLine().split(",");`

Comment: `Eric Jablow` already commented on this situation.  I will post a suggestion on the `while` loop logic into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that popped out at me you rely on an internal if conditional to break the loop.  Instead of that, you can use the test as part of the `while` loop like

```
BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
String line = fin.readLine();
while (line != null) {
  //execute code here
  line = fin.readLine();
}
```

This is better because you don't have to worry about working with null values inside the loop and can get rid of that break statement inside the while loop.

In addition, are you **certain** that you have `BufferedReader`, `FileReader` and `Part` classes in the import statements?  If you can't create a new `Part`, that will throw a NPE in that line.

To test if you you can access the `Part` object:

```
Part newPart = new Part(/*add all constructor args*/);
if (newPart != null) {
  System.out.println("Non-null Part");
  partList.add(newPart);
}
```

If you get the console output, then the part object has been added to the list.  If not, that is where your error is.

Comment: Yep, all of that was working fine, I've done enough with File I/O in class to know how to set them up, I just didn't know how to transfer that data to the new class effectively.